# Would the “App history” in task manager record app history correctly after the computer was restarted due to blue screen of death?

Tags: windows-10, bsod, cpu-usage, task-manager

E.g. I was using an application before the BSoD show up. Would the CPU time of this application as recorded by task manager be less than it actually is?

I am using windows 10.

Comment: nothing gets logged but a crash dump during a bsod, so task manager is no help.

Comment: @Moab Is there any way that the crash dump could tell me whether an application was open when the system was crashed? I need it to assess the data loss. Why am I using the task manager is that if the crash happened e.g. today, I would forward the system time to 1 month later to see the CPU time of the app of today only. If the CPU time was 0 (or the app entry does not show up), then I would know that this app was not open at the time the system crashed.

Comment: Event viewer does not log the crash, but logs that the computer was not shut down cleanly on next boot, so this would give a approx time of crash. Yes a full dump file would show everything that was running at time of crash and possibilities of what caused it., but dump files are not easy to read (debug). Requires experience to debug them properly.

Comment: I am using WinDbg. After running the suggested "!analyze -v" I could not find "chrome.exe" in the output, although I am sure that chrome was open at that time. Do you know the correct command to find all processes that was running at the time of crash?

Comment: You can answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1583435/is-there-any-way-to-find-which-app-was-being-when-a-windows-10-system-crashed-vi