# Is there any way to find which app was being when a windows 10 system crashed via blue screen of death?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, crash, windbg

Since I would like to access which data was lost, I would like to see which app was open when the BSoD happened. The system in concern is a Windows 10.

I have a WinDbg preview. After running the suggested "!analyze -v" I could not find "chrome.exe" in the output, although I am sure that Google chrome was open at that time. Do anyone know the correct command to find all processes that were running at the time of crash?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112777/discussion-on-question-by-aqqqq-is-there-any-way-to-find-which-app-was-being-whe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel dumpfile created from the crash contains all running processes at the time of the crash.

1. Open the dumpfile with Windbg
2. Run `!process 0 0`